# How does mongodb use an index to count documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

According to docs, `db.collection.countDocuments()` wraps this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: <query> },
   { $group: { _id: null, n: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

Even if there is an index, all of the matched docs will be passed into the `$group` to be counted, no?

If not, how is mongodb able to count the docs without processing all matching docs?

Comment: Sometimes it processes all of the matching docs.  Depending on the filter, some counts can be covered by the index - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB query planner can make some optimizations.

In that sample aggregation, it can see that no fields are required except for the ones referenced in `<query>`, so it can add an implicit `$project` stage to select only those fields.

If those fields and the _id are all included in a single index, there is no need to fetch the documents to execute that query, all the necessary information is available from the index.

Comment: But still, does it have to count the index? Is there enough information to derive the total count with some arithmetic? That's actually the meat of the question.

Comment: It scans the index, yes.  There is no mechanism to return the number of keys in an index range without reading each index entry.

Comment: Log lines, profiler entries, explain output etc help confirm this